# How to deal with if subquery returns null in Having clause

Tags: mysql

Here is my query, how to deal with subquery returning null.

```
SELECT 
    p.parent_id, 
    i.*, 
    IF(p.parent_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS has_child_rows,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'lang', itt.lang,
            'title', itt.title 
        )
    ) AS lang
FROM 
    image_tree i
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT parent_id 
        FROM image_tree 
        WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY parent_id
    ) p ON i.id = p.parent_id
    LEFT JOIN image_tree_title as itt  
        ON itt.image_tree_id = i.id
GROUP BY i.url 
HAVING i.parent_id = (
    SELECT FROM image_tree where image_tree.id = 77
)
```

How can I deal with the case when the subquery in my `HAVING` clause:

```
(SELECT FROM image_tree where image_tree.id = 77)
```

returns `NULL`, but I still want to compare that value with `i.parent_id` and match when they are both `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make this work would be to replace both values with a value which is impossible for `i.parent_id` e.g. `-1` when they are `NULL` i.e.

```
HAVING IFNULL(i.parent_id, -1) = IFNULL((SELECT parent_id 
                                         FROM image_tree
                                         WHERE image_tree.id = 77), -1)
```

Note you are missing `parent_id` in the columns part of the subquery.

Comment: Thank you sir please vote my question if you found it usefull

Comment: Sir is there a way to optimize this query since i get sql_mode=only_full_group_by error?

Comment: @Ambulancelada you would need to include all the columns you are fetching in the `GROUP BY` clause. Without knowing exactly what results you want to achieve it's hard to answer. It's probably worth another question...